# Calculating age derived from current date and DOB

Tags: sql

I'm trying to calculate the age of a user based on the current year and his year of birth, but something in my syntax appears to be incorrect and I can't spot it.

```
CREATE TABLE Normal_Users(

first_name varchar(20),
last_name varchar(20),
date_of_birth date,
age int = year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - year(date_of_birth) 
)
```

Why is this incorrect?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: It doesn't take into account month/day. If current timestamp is "5/1/2021", and DoB is '6/1/2015', the year difference is 6, but the month indicates there is still another month before the person is 6, so they currently are 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `AS`:

```
CREATE TABLE Normal_Users(
first_name varchar(20),
last_name varchar(20),
date_of_birth date,
age int AS (year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - year(date_of_birth))
);
```

**[`Generated columns in MySQL`](http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/)**

> < type>   [ GENERATED ALWAYS ]   **AS   ( < expression> )**  [
>   VIRTUAL|STORED ] [ UNIQUE [KEY] ]   [ [PRIMARY] KEY ]   [ NOT NULL ]
>   [ COMMENT  ]

If you are using `SQL Server` there is no need for datatype in **[`computed columns`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**:

```
CREATE TABLE Normal_Users(
    first_name varchar(20),
    last_name varchar(20),
    date_of_birth date,
    age  AS (year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - year(date_of_birth))
    );
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/387740)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

For calculating age better use:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, date_of_birth,  CURDATE()) AS age;
```

Your code for `2014-12-31` and `2015-01-01` will return 1 year, but really it has 0.

Comment: This works fine, but is there a way to use equals instead of as? I remember using it before but I don't exactly remember how.

Comment: @Swailem95 What RDBMS do you use? SQL Server? Maybe it was view: `CREATE VIEW name AS SELECT age = year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - year(date_of_birth) FROM table`

Answer (score 2):

How do you do it in your brain?
You subtract the year of birth from current year,
Then you if the birthday already happen this year.
If Yes fine, else it means he will have this year the age (so -1 yearold)

diff of the years is easy.
how to compare month and day to know if we are before or after
month*100+day which gives a number MMDD
which is easy to compare bigger equal or smaller, so after birthday, day of birthday, before birthday.

Here is the principle for Sybase :

```
declare @test char(10)
set @test='15/02/2010'

select "age" =
case when (month(convert(datetime, @test, 103))*100)+day(convert(datetime, @test, 103)) - ((month(getdate())*100)+day(getdate())) <= 0 then
    DATEDIFF(YEAR,convert(datetime, @test, 103),getdate())
else
    DATEDIFF(YEAR,convert(datetime, @test, 103),getdate())-1
end
```

Comment: Downvoted, but also the only correct answer that accounts for when WITHIN the year the birthdate is. All others that just compare the two years will be wrong if the current date is earlier *in the year* than the person's month/day of birth.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `as` keyword instead of equals:

```
CREATE TABLE Normal_Users(
   first_name varchar(20),
   last_name varchar(20),
   date_of_birth date,
   age int AS (year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - year(date_of_birth)) 
)
```

Comment: Still incorrect. You MUST account for actual month and day. If person born 5/1/2015, and today is 6/1/2021, yours returns 6, but person is actually still 5 for another month.

Answer (score 1):

You have to account not only for the year, but the month/day within the year. For SQL Server, below shows both cases, where year alone is used (and gets it wrong), and with the date within the year used to correct it when the birthdate month/day is later in the year than the reference (current) month day.

```
declare @DoB date = '6/1/2015';
declare @CurrDate date = '5/1/2021';

select YEAR(@CurrDate)-YEAR(@Dob);  -- will be incorrectly "6"

select YEAR(@CurrDate)-YEAR(@Dob) 
    - case when (MONTH(@DOB)*100 + DAY(@DOB)) > (MONTH(@CurrDate) + DAY(@CurrDate)) then 1 else 0 end;  -- correctly shows "5"
```

Comment: Note how I used month/day. You can't use things like DATENAME or DATEPART with "dayofyear", because, for example, in leap years, March 1 will be one day later than in non-leap years, making the comparison incorrect in those cases.

Answer (score -1):

Considering the case where the date of birth is in December and you are running the query in January, you need this sort of thing.

```
select int(
datediff(day, current_date, birth_date) / 365.25
) as yearsOld
```

The exact syntax depends on the database engine which hasn't been specified.

Comment: No day-math is going to do it. Even leap years aren't every 4 years.
https://www.nbcdfw.com/weather/weather-connection/a-leap-year-does-not-happen-every-4-years/2321237/